# How to use constrained identity functions with classes?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-generics

I want to make an Item system where to create an item, you can declare it in `makeItems`. I also want each item to be able to reference another item, such as `cost` being another item in the registry.

This code uses constrained identity functions, and is fully functional:

```
const makeItems = <K extends PropertyKey, C extends K>(
  items: Record<K, {cost?: C}>
) => items
const items = makeItems({
  money: {},
  dirt: {
    cost: "money", // typescript autocompletes to "dirt" | "money"
  },
})
```

Now the issue is when I want to switch from objects to classes.
Now I have a base item class:

```
class Item<T extends string> {
  public cost?: T;
  constructor() {
  }
  public setCost(item: T) {
    this.cost = item;
    return this;
  }
}
```

My updated code for declaring items wouldn't look that much different:

```
const makeItems = <T extends string, C extends T>(items: Record<T, Item<C>>) => items;
const items = makeItems({
  money: new Item(),
  dirt: new Item().setCost("money")
})
```

However, updating the code to classes ends up with an error on "money" and "dirt":

```
Type 'Item<string>' is not assignable to type 'Item<"money" | "dirt">'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"money" | "dirt"'.
```

How do I get rid of the error while still allowing typescript to infer the itemIDs?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/PTAECpwZwSwWwA4BsYDMYFMAmoDGB7LDSAKBFACEBDKDUASQBcM48kaoAaUAdwAsYuPqBhRQAV1o5G+PACcMVZqAB2GHiOZwoAOhK52UMUxYAeACqgMAD2YqsYqIzkwVAcwB8oAN4lQoBHEAIxRcPHwnAH4ALlBzAG4-cJUnOXFcGTkACgBKHySAXyTAkMFQWkYAYQjGLJgtWPM8339-RgFdAidQAF5NFkTW0AVGcTkVUHbRQdAiov18FMZQOCoAawwTbV7QCytbDHtHZ1c3bkr9uwc4jzqtKFiAJQwCOSwLbi3TSo8PPJ6vPUWFBEgQlv1tn1VhstlAsi0VosMABPWJqDRbXKcJJYGByRho9QMLS5HQVapOLIAIjgSORVJyJAKjKAA)

Comment: Since you don't pass the generic to the `Item` it is inferred as just `string` which is not assignable to `dirt | money`. `setCost` also doesn't change the type of generic parameter, it still remains the `string`. An uncomfortable and maybe useless solution is to pass the generic parameter manually like in [here](https://tsplay.dev/mpAQpW)

Comment: @wonderflame a little bit confused on how it works with the first example not the second

Comment: in the first example, you pass the literal value `{cost: "money"}`. In the second you use a generic class which accepts a parameter that is constrained by string

Comment: . @SimplyNo consider 1) make `makeItems` use `{cost: T}` to construct new Items itself  2) `new Item<T>({ cost: T }): Item<T>` 3) `item.setCost<V>(cost: V): Item<V>` 4) `class Item<Y extends string = any>`